# Use checkstyle to require space on either side of equals

Tags: java, checkstyle

How do you set checkstyle to enforce the following:

```
int i = 0;
if(i == 0) {
    // do something
}
if(i > 0) {
    // do something
}
```

instead of:

```
int i=0;
if(i==0) {
    // do something
}
if(i>0) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule name is `WhitespaceAround` and you can set it up like this in the checkstyle xml file:

```
<module name="WhitespaceAround">
  <property name="tokens" value="ASSIGN,BAND,BAND_ASSIGN,BOR,BOR_ASSIGN,BSR,BSR_ASSIGN,BXOR,BXOR_ASSIGN,COLON,DIV,DIV_ASSIGN,EQUAL,GE,GT,LAND,LE,LITERAL_ASSERT,LITERAL_CATCH,LITERAL_DO,LITERAL_ELSE,LITERAL_FINALLY,LITERAL_FOR,LITERAL_IF,LITERAL_RETURN,LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED,LITERAL_TRY,LITERAL_WHILE,LOR,LT,MINUS,MINUS_ASSIGN,MOD,MOD_ASSIGN,NOT_EQUAL,PLUS,PLUS_ASSIGN,QUESTION,SL,SLIST,SL_ASSIGN,SR,SR_ASSIGN,STAR,STAR_ASSIGN,LITERAL_ASSERT,TYPE_EXTENSION_AND,WILDCARD_TYPE"/>
</module>
```

You can refer to the following URL:
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_whitespace.html

Answer (score 1):

User similar configuration in xml

```
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="TreeWalker">
      <module name="WhitespaceAfter"/>
      <module name="WhitespaceAround"/>
   </module>
</module>
```